# How to use struct declared in header file from source file c++?

Tags: c++, struct

I have a header file (abc.hpp) as bellow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
class ABC {
public:
        struct BoxPoint {
            float x;
            float y;
        } ;
        vector<BoxPoint> getBoxPoint();
```

Then, in the source file (abc.cpp):

```
#include "abc.hpp"
vector<BoxPoint> ABC::getBoxPoint(){
   vector<BoxPoint> boxPointsl;
   BoxPoint xy = {box.x1, box.y1};
   boxPointsl.push_back(xy);
   return boxPointsl
}
```

When I compile, there is error:

```
error: ‘BoxPoint’ was not declared in this scope
```

at line `vector<BoxPoint> ABC::getBoxPoint()`

If I change to `void ABC::getBoxPoint()`, (also change in the header file and remove `return boxPointsl`, the error does not exist.
Can you point me to why display the error and how to resolve it?
Thank you!

Comment: You're asking for `vector<BoxPoint>`, not `vector<ABC::BoxPoint>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the symbol `BoxPoint` was only known inside `ABC` scope, outside you have to add the `ABC` scope, so `ABC::BoxPoint`:

```
#include "abc.hpp"
vector<ABC::BoxPoint> ABC::getBoxPoint(){
   vector<BoxPoint> boxPointsl;
   BoxPoint xy = {box.x1, box.y1};
   boxPointsl.push_back(xy);
   return boxPointsl
}
```

Inside the function you can use `BoxPoint` again, since we are inside the `ABC` scope again.

Comment: You don't need the `ABC::` prefix *inside* the function body, as it is considered in the scope.

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved my this problem!